# My Adafruit PITFT stops working after sudo apt-get update

Tags: kernel, pitft

My PiTFT was working fine, with the custom image flashed on the SD Card. But for downloading programs, they say to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get update`. I do this, then reboot, now I get a white underscore in the upper-left corner. I  ssh into the Pi and run `sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel=1.20161027-1`. Then I reboot again and it boots up only showing a white screen. Now I can't SSH into it anymore.

I am using a Pi 3 3.5" TFT

Answer (score 4):

Per the [Adafruit Help! FAQ](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/easy-install?view=all#faq):

> Doing an apt-get upgrade or rpi-update will blow away the custom PiTFT
>   kernel.

You will have to reinstall the kernel.

If you had already made a working PiTFT setup, you may be able to reinstall the Adafruit kernel like so:

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel=1.20161027-1
```

If it tells you that the latest version is already installed, try this instead:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-kernel=1.20161027-1
```

...you can check [here](https://apt.adafruit.com/raspbian/pool/main/r/raspberrypi-firmware/) and substitute the most recent version you see in the =1.20161027-1 part.

Comment: I had the same issue I think I did it 3 times in total. Like Steve Robillard said you can't upgrade the kernel that way, you would have to get adafruits latest. To prevent myself from making the same mistake I set /boot to Read only in FSTAB proc /proc proc defaults 0 0 PARTUUID=f0b6fc3c-01 /boot vfat ro,noatime 0 2 PARTUUID=f0b6fc3c-02 / ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1

Comment: This may be useful, with the caveat that it does have side effects, but it does not solve the OP's problem.